# Sql check multiple values from string array

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What I'm trying to do is I have a string array that has 1 or more values.  When I pass those values to sql I'm trying to check one field on each value if it contains pass or fail.  I am able to do this for a one to one.  But now the requirements are that multiple values or ids need to be checked at the same time.  I'm not really even sure where to start with this one.  Most articles suggest storing information in a table.  The reason being for the Top 1 as some of the data already has had failed status.  So I'm looking for the most recent fail stauts

Here is the sql to check for one ID:

```
declare @PTSID = '7VD6GSZG'
Select top (1)
p_id,   
insp_status 
from Insp_Results   
where RESV_PTSID = @PTSID
order by RESD_DATE desc
```

But say i have something like this

```
declare @PTSID nvarchar(1000) = '7VD6GSZG, 8V9WKX78, DOJUSEM8'
```

How can I check each ID for the column inspection status?
So Ideally I'd like something like

```
p_id      |   insp_status
7VD6GSZG      fail
8V9WKX78      fail
DOJUSEM8      pass
```

Comment: You'll need to parse that comma delimited string in order to put single quotes around each value : '7VD6GSZG', '8V9WKX78', 'DOJUSEM8' .  You'll also need to change your WHERE condition from = to IN :  `where RESV_PTSID IN (@PTSID)` .  What isn't clear in your question is why you're selecting TOP (1).  You need to explain that so we know how to answer your question.

Comment: ^ `where column in (@variable)` is a pointless construct that degrades to `where column = @variable`. You can't compare against multiple values in this way. You would need to use a subquery. The subquery could reference a table variable, but still a query would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to change string to table like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[function_string_to_table]
(
    @string VARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(
    data VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)

    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN
        IF @end = 0 
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (data) 
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))
        SET @start = @end + 1
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END

    RETURN

END
```

Then join with your table like this:

```
declare @PTSID nvarchar(1000) = '7VD6GSZG, 8V9WKX78, DOJUSEM8'

select *, CASE WHEN CHECKT.data is null THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END as dataExists 
from Insp_Results  R 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[function_string_to_table](@PTSID, ',') CHECKT ON CHECKT.data = R.RESV_PTSID
```

Comment: This does work but I cant find both values.  I've changed the join to an inner but still I only get one ID never both at the same time

Comment: Maybe you need to invert it:
select *, CASE WHEN CHECKT.data is null THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END as dataExists 
from [dbo].[function_string_to_table](@PTSID, ',') CHECKT  
LEFT JOIN Insp_Results  R ON CHECKT.data = R.RESV_PTSID    Is this what you need ? I do not understand correctly.

Comment: Using a splitter with a loop is the absolute slowest possible method for splitting strings. Please see this article for a number of alternatives that will perform far better. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score -2):

You can use the SQL IN condition. The syntax for is:

```
    expression IN (value1, value2, .... value_n);
```

so in your case it could be something like:

```
    declare @PTSID = nvarchar(1000);
    SET @PTSID = '7VD6GSZG, 8V9WKX78, DOJUSEM8';
    Select top (1)
    p_id,   
    insp_status 
    from Insp_Results   
    where RESV_PTSID IN @PTSID
    order by RESD_DATE desc
```

Comment: `where column in (@variable)` is a pointless construct that degrades to `where column = @variable`. You can't compare against multiple values in this way. Your answer is looking for 1 row where `REV_PTSID` is equal to that entire comma-delimited value.